# Writing an if/then statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I write a selector so that it says

```
var myDefault;
if $('th.default') {
   myDefault = $('th.default');
} else {
   myDefault = $('th:eq(2)'); // 3rd column
}
```

It probably uses something like:

```
var myDefault = $('th.default') || $('th:eq(2)');
```

except the first selection is not returning falsey if there is no th with a class="default".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myDefault = $('th.default');
if (!myDefault.length) { myDefault = $('th:eq(2)'); }
```

Comment: Even though Eli updated his answer to be like mine, mine still is the more correct way to go.  For caching he creates 2 variables and mine only creates 1. You don't need the ternary operation.  You only need to redefine `myDefault` in the case that the orginal jQuery object `$('th.default')` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

```
var myDefault = $('th.default').length ? $('th.default') : $('th:eq(2)');
```

Or, if you LOVE caching :) :

```
var defaultElement = $('th.default');
var myDefault = defaultElement.length ? defaultElement : $('th:eq(2)');
```

Comment: Why re-query the DOM for the same jQuery object?  Use should use caching like my solution uses, which in turn means that you don't need the ternary solution.

Comment: I agree and is what I use in my solutions. I am simply just showing how to use the ternary to switch between elements, not as production code.

Comment: I figured as much.  I just wanted to definitely point out, since you didn't originally, that you always want to cache jQuery objects and never re-query the same object if you don't have to.  Even though the OP was trying to do a makeshift ternary, to me, that really isn't the most efficient way of going about things since when you cache $('th.default') into myDefault, you'd only need to redefine myDefault in the case that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Eli, I think I'll use Scott's solution because it looks a little more self documenting.  I am new to JavaScript and like the more verbose if/then construct than the ternary operator.  I realize that my question lent itself to using a ternary operator, but I was stymied on how to determine whether the selection was empty or not.  This comment is probably TMI.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDefault;
if ($('th.default').length) {
   myDefault = $('th.default');
} else {
   myDefault = $('th:eq(2)'); // 3rd column
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
if $('th.default').length {}
```

Your conditional returns true, as all objects are true. Your object could be an empty jQuery selector, but this would still return true. If your selector has no matches, `length` returns "0", which is falsy.

**Edit**: I had this as a method... should have been a property!

Comment: `length` is not a function.. but `size()` is.

Comment: As far as I know there is no jQuery length function.

Comment: @TheSuperTramp and @Eli http://api.jquery.com/length/ The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Comment: It's a property, not a function. It's `.length` not `.length()`.

Comment: @two7s_clash ~ yeah, I know what you mean, but that's still not a function.

Answer (score 1):

`$('th.default')` will return a jQuery object, so it will never be `false`.

You can use array notation to check the element: `$('th.default')[0]` will return `true` if elements were matched (and will contain the first matched element) or will return `false` if there are no matched elements.

You can test and set `myDefault` with a ternary operator:

```
var myDefault = $('th.default')[0] ? $('th.default') : $('th:eq(1)');
```

[Here's a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/h5cKe/) Just remove `class="default"` to switch between the two.